# Write a SQL Query to find year from date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

First of all I've try to do this query, in different format. but, I have not get any solution. so, i wants to solve this doubt in particular method and different method. And I want the exact solution this table.

**Write a SQL Query to find  year from date.**

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) as "Year";
```

---

```
   o_id         no.order          o_date         amount 
    --------------------------------------------------
    2             6                1-2-11         120
    3             7                2-2-11         130
    5             5                3-2-11         100
    6             1                4-2-11         50
```

note: [the source getting from](http://java67.blogspot.in/2013/04/10-frequently-asked-sql-query-interview-questions-answers-database.html)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @Bart van Nierop, thanks for response. but, i want the solution.

Comment: Could you explain what is the input data and what exactly is desired output?

Comment: "thanks for the response but i want the solution". If I understand correctly, that means "give me the solution ready and save me the pain of doing some research". That's not the way StackOverflow works! You have to show that you have made some effort to help yourself. Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @ Barranka, take vote for one 'userful comment'. You right and I know it very well. I've tried and got the solution( SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) as "Year";), but I want the different and variety solution only. Any way thanks for comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE());
```

Source: [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

Or

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(GETDATE(), '%Y');
```

Source: [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Example:

```
SELECT  o_id, amount, YEAR(o_date) as year
FROM your_table
```

Comment: where can i give a input.

Comment: You can try this:- SELECT DATE_FORMAT(inputdate, '%Y'); Also do check the format of your date

Comment: Dear anonymous down voter, please tell me why you down voted so that I may edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
select YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('1-2-11','%d-%m-%Y')) year;
```

Comment: Add to your answer, *If the stored dates are in `dd-mm-yy` format, then ...*. +1 though.

Answer (score 1):

Bart already pointed to the solution... manual has a line :

```
mysql> SELECT YEAR('1987-01-01');
        -> 1987
```